# A paper by Viggo Brun

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

Does any one know a digital link to Viggo Brun's paper: "Deux transformations elementaires de la fonction Z de Riemann" Revista Ci. Lima 41 (1939), 517-25. ??

Comment: Apparently, the "official webpage" of the journal is https://sisbib.unmsm.edu.pe/bibvirtual/publicaciones/rev_ciencias/portada.htm. The journal "Revista de Ciencias (Lima)" is not currently active, and was published by Universidad Nacional Mayor de San Marcos (Lima, Perú). Perhaps you could write to the librarian, whose page is https://sisbib.unmsm.edu.pe/.

Comment: The article is also reviewed in both MR and zbMATH (which is now open). Also, zbMATH https://www.zbmath.org/serials/?q=se%3A3613 confirms that the journal I wrote above is the correct one.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I really appreciate the info. I will contact the link and try to get access to the paper. Brun is a Colossus of XXth century mathematics: without him his disciple Selberg would have been quite unknown. It is a shame that his papers are so scattered...